Flutter Table Calendar - Flutter How to get data from external link JSON
I am new to flutter/Dart programming I would like to get data from external link JSON display events on the calendar of the table_calendar plugin
My Calendar
events_exemple.dart
// Copyright 2019 Aleksander Woźniak
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';

import '../utils.dart';

class TableEventsExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TableEventsExampleState createState() => _TableEventsExampleState();
}

class _TableEventsExampleState extends State<TableEventsExample> {
  late final ValueNotifier<List<Event>> _selectedEvents;
  CalendarFormat _calendarFormat = CalendarFormat.month;
  RangeSelectionMode _rangeSelectionMode = RangeSelectionMode
      .toggledOff; // Can be toggled on/off by longpressing a date
  DateTime _focusedDay = DateTime.now();
  DateTime? _selectedDay;
  DateTime? _rangeStart;
  DateTime? _rangeEnd;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _selectedDay = _focusedDay;
    _selectedEvents = ValueNotifier(_getEventsForDay(_selectedDay!));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _selectedEvents.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  List<Event> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day) {
    // Implementation example
    return kEvents[day] ?? [];
  }

  List<Event> _getEventsForRange(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
    // Implementation example
    final days = daysInRange(start, end);

    return [
      for (final d in days) ..._getEventsForDay(d),
    ];
  }

  void _onDaySelected(DateTime selectedDay, DateTime focusedDay) {
    if (!isSameDay(_selectedDay, selectedDay)) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedDay = selectedDay;
        _focusedDay = focusedDay;
        _rangeStart = null; // Important to clean those
        _rangeEnd = null;
        _rangeSelectionMode = RangeSelectionMode.toggledOff;
      });

      _selectedEvents.value = _getEventsForDay(selectedDay);
    }
  }

  void _onRangeSelected(DateTime? start, DateTime? end, DateTime focusedDay) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedDay = null;
      _focusedDay = focusedDay;
      _rangeStart = start;
      _rangeEnd = end;
      _rangeSelectionMode = RangeSelectionMode.toggledOn;
    });

    // `start` or `end` could be null
    if (start != null && end != null) {
      _selectedEvents.value = _getEventsForRange(start, end);
    } else if (start != null) {
      _selectedEvents.value = _getEventsForDay(start);
    } else if (end != null) {
      _selectedEvents.value = _getEventsForDay(end);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('TableCalendar - Events'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TableCalendar<Event>(
            firstDay: kFirstDay,
            lastDay: kLastDay,
            focusedDay: _focusedDay,
            selectedDayPredicate: (day) => isSameDay(_selectedDay, day),
            rangeStartDay: _rangeStart,
            rangeEndDay: _rangeEnd,
            calendarFormat: _calendarFormat,
            rangeSelectionMode: _rangeSelectionMode,
            eventLoader: _getEventsForDay,
            startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
            calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
              // Use `CalendarStyle` to customize the UI
              outsideDaysVisible: false,
            ),
            onDaySelected: _onDaySelected,
            onRangeSelected: _onRangeSelected,
            onFormatChanged: (format) {
              if (_calendarFormat != format) {
                setState(() {
                  _calendarFormat = format;
                });
              }
            },
            onPageChanged: (focusedDay) {
              _focusedDay = focusedDay;
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          Expanded(
            child: ValueListenableBuilder<List<Event>>(
              valueListenable: _selectedEvents,
              builder: (context, value, _) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: value.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 12.0,
                        vertical: 4.0,
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                      ),
                      child: ListTile(
                        onTap: () => print('${value[index]}'),
                        title: Text('${value[index]}'),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

utils.dart
import 'dart:collection';
  import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
  import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

  import 'mcf.dart';


  /// Example event class.
  class Event {
    final String title;

    const Event(this.title);

    @override
    String toString() => title;
  }

  // LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<AppEvent>>? _groupedEvents;
  class AppEvent {
    late int id;
    late String description;
    late String title;
    late DateTime start;
    late DateTime end;
  }

  //this is the code am trying to use, and its not running nor giving an error

  Map<DateTime, List<Event>> _kEventSource = {};

  Future<List<Events>> mike() async {
    String url ='';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    // print(response.body);
    if(response.statusCode == 200){

      // print("response is 200");

      List jsonData = Events.FromMap(response.body).toList();
      // print(jsonData);

      jsonData.forEach((element) {
        // print(element.date.substring(8,10));
        int year = int.parse(element.date.substring(0,4));
        int month = int.parse(element.date.substring(5,7));
        int day = int.parse(element.date.substring(8,10));
        _kEventSource[DateTime(
          year,
          month,
          day,
        )] = _kEventSource[DateTime(
          year,
          month,
          day,
        )] != null
            ? [
          ...?_kEventSource[DateTime(
            year,
            month,
            day,
          )],
          Event(element.title)
        ]
            : [Event(element.title)];
      });
      return Events.FromMap(response.body).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }



  /// Example events.
  /// Using a [LinkedHashMap] is highly recommended if you decide to use a map.
  final kEvents = LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<Event>>(
    equals: isSameDay,
    hashCode: getHashCode,
    // actual code
  )..addAll(_kEventSource);

  // the actual code that comes with the package, this code generates events which will
  //be displayed on the calender, i have commented it so that i can use my own code the
  //above code

  int getHashCode(DateTime key) {
    return key.day * 1000000 + key.month * 10000 + key.year;
  }

  /// Returns a list of [DateTime] objects from [first] to [last], inclusive.
  List<DateTime> daysInRange(DateTime first, DateTime last) {
    final dayCount = last.difference(first).inDays + 1;
    // print(dayCount);
    return List.generate(
      dayCount,
          (index) => DateTime.utc(first.year, first.month, first.day + index),
    );
  }

  final kToday = DateTime.now();
  final kFirstDay = DateTime(2024);
  final kLastDay = DateTime(2040);

This is the Event data model:
mcf.dart
import 'dart:convert';
class Events {
  final String description;
  final String start;
  final String end;
  final int id;
  final String title;
  Events({
    required this.description,
    required this.start,
    required this.end,
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
  });


  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'description': description,
      'start': start,
      'end': end,
      'id': id,
      'title': title,
    };
  }

  factory Events.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Events(
      description: map['description'] ?? "",
      start: map['start'] ?? "",
      end: map['end'] ?? "",
      id: map['id'] ?? 0,
      title: map["title"] ?? "",
    );
  }
  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Events.fromJson(String source) => Events.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}

I hope anyone can give me an answer on how to get data from external JSON.
Thank you

Thank you for your feedback, yes I consulted this page and when I import my external JSON to a list or a grid it works.
I have difficulty importing with the table_calendar package.
I use the example code from the table_calendar package
events_example.dart
and
utils.dart
I would like when we select a date to display the list of events and when we click on event to display the event details
